# How to fix a Front door sticks out (from the inside slightly)

Tags: doors, hinges

I had a new front door (with frame) installed recently. The door seems to be sticking out (from the inside) in the upper left corner causing it not to seal tight against the weather stripping. Any ideas how to fix this? The door seems level as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's installed incorrectly.

This happens when the hinge side and latch side are not both truly vertical. In this case, the top of the hinged side is installed too far towards the interior. On closing the door, it will first contact the bottom of the latch side which then prevents the top of the latch side from closing fully

Your installer should fix this, it is because of poor workmanship

Comment: Thanks. The door came as one large piece framed with sidelights. Do you think this was an issue when the manufacturer setup the door, sidelights into the frame or when the installer installed the entire piece?

Comment: Even with a framed unit that includes sidelights it is possible to get it installed wrong so that the door will not fit properly.

Comment: while it is possible that it occurred at the manufacturer it's unlikely, also it wouldn't change the fact that the installer is responsible. Part of the installation process is literally to check the swing and closure, that is how it's adjusted properly, there is no way to install the door correctly and not be aware of the issue. It follows then, yes, they did know that it did not close right when they installed it.

Comment: We had a clown of a contractor and fired him. Guess our new contractor will have to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this problem have a name? The only thing I found was that the door is "out of plane" but I can't find a single tutorial on Youtube for "repairing an out of plane door" which makes me thing I don't have the right name.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks as though the door was not installed properly.  When hanging a door it's important to make sure it's level but also straight so that you don't get the frame twisting and leaving the door unable to close properly as you are seeing.

I know of no quick-and-dirty solutions that will resolve this.  The solution is to remove the trim, square the door with shims as necessary until it's both level and straight.  The test of a properly hung door is that it doesn't swing by itself and it closes such that it contacts the seal all the way around.

I'm sure you paid for a job-well-done but it appears you didn't get that.  I'd call the folks that did this and have them back out to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks. The door came as one large piece framed with sidelights. Do you think this was an issue when the manufacturer installed the door, sidelights into the frame or when the installer installed the entire piece?

Comment: I'm sure it's the installation.  The manufacturer almost certainly has fixtures that ensure the entire assembly is aligned correctly.  Regardless of the sidelights, the installation issue is the same.  The door frame is twisted in the opening and that prevents the door itself from making contact all the way around.